# How to force Help and Printer Setup Dialogs to be displayed on the same monitor as the running application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I know how to force forms to appear on the same monitor as the running application, but I do not see how to ask the Help or the Printer Setup dialogs to display on the same monitor. The Help displays where it displayed last time, but we want it to show up on the application monitor.  The Printer Setup dialog always seems to appear on the primary monitor

Answer (score 1):

Passing the parent form's `Handle` to `TPrinterSetupDialog.Execute` seems to do the trick.

```
if PrinterSetupDialog1.Execute(Self.Handle) then
  //
```

Using Delphi 7 (where the `TPrinterSetupDialog.Execute` does not accept a parameter), you have two choices.

The easiest would be to create your own descendant of `TPrinterSetupDialog`. `Execute` is virtual in `TCommonDialog`, the ancestor of `TPrinterSetupDialog`, where it is overridden. You could override it in your own descendant, use the code in the `TPrinterSetupDialog` as a basis for your own `Execute` override, adding `overload` as well. Your overloaded `Execute` would accept a `ParentHandle: HWND` parameter, and set the `PrintDlgRec.hWndOwner` to that provided window handle.

I thought about trying to write this for you (or at least get it started), but there are additional things you'd have to copy from the `Dialogs` unit (functions that are defined in the implementation section that wrap some API calls, and the callback function that's used for the dialog's message loop), and I don't have D7 available where I'm at to even try to compile it.

The other alternative (as David Heffernan mentioned in his comment below) would be to call the Windows API [PrintDlgEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly yourself. This is discussed in MSDN, in the [Print Dialog Box (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topic. Once again, I don't have D7 available, so I can't really give you an example of using it from Delphi. (I checked, and don't have one tucked away anywhere.)

I'm not sure you can set the help window's position; I think that's done automatically by Windows based on the user's prior use. (I haven't been able to so so, anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, but you tagged your question Delphi **2007**, which does. :-)

Comment: Right you are!  My confusion!  The Help issue is under Delphi 2007.  The Printer Setup issue is inside a DLL that is invoked from the Delphi 2007 app; unfortunately (?!?), the DLL is written in Delphi 7.

Comment: And you can't recompile the DLL under 2007? They're pretty much directly compatible.

Comment: If you cannot recompile then you may need to invoke the common dialog directly win win32 code and pass hwndOwner. +1

Comment: Delphi 2007 and Delphi 7 may be compatible, but the components and libraries that we use are not.   I have been told that moving the DLL to Delphi 2007 would be arduous.

Comment: David: can you provide an example of how to invoke the dialog directly with win32 code please?

Comment: Ken: I tried to create my own print dialog derivative in a separate unit, but eventually the code refers to private variables (FHandle in DialogHoook), so that attempt fails.  I considered modifying the Dialogs unit, but it is never compiled (at least the way I have the IDE set up) so that does not seem to work.  I looked at the MSDN article, but it is beyond me.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @jon Not in this question. Ken's already answered the question that you asked.